# AWS S3 bucket content access using cloudflare DNS record

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudflare

i have a aws s3 bucket with the name development-assets.example.com and i have a .png file in it . now i want to access the bucket using cloudflare

attached below bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::development-assets.example.com/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "173.245.48.0/20",
                        "103.21.244.0/22",
                        "103.22.200.0/22",
                        "103.31.4.0/22",
                        "141.101.64.0/18",
                        "108.162.192.0/18",
                        "190.93.240.0/20",
                        "188.114.96.0/20",
                        "197.234.240.0/22",
                        "198.41.128.0/17",
                        "162.158.0.0/15",
                        "104.16.0.0/13",
                        "104.24.0.0/14",
                        "172.64.0.0/13",
                        "131.0.72.0/22",
                        "2400:cb00::/32",
                        "2606:4700::/32",
                        "2803:f800::/32",
                        "2405:b500::/32",
                        "2405:8100::/32",
                        "2a06:98c0::/29",
                        "2c0f:f248::/32"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and in cloudflare i have created a DNS record as

cname - development-assets

content - development-assets.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com

turned on proxied

SSL/ TLS setting changed to flexible

now in my local browser when i tried to execute http://development-assets.example.com/test.png

i'm getting AccessDeniedAccess Denied

can you please help me? i tried many different ways like including by IP address in the policy but still got the AccessDenied.

i am not sure what mistake i'm making?